# Automatation of specific tasks

Tags: networking, 19.10, automation, events

Our company just moved to another office and had the entire network at the office redesigned.
Our WiFi is setup in a way that we only may connect and get access to the internal business resources if you’ve got an managed Windows client. For all other clients ex. macs and Linux machines, when we connect to that same WiFi, we are connected to the Bring Your Own Device network which only has internet access, and not internal resource and we need to use VPN. This might get a little tedious at some point.

After that short little story, comes my little question.

Are there anyone which has done some automation of certain tasks where the tasks are run when the computer connects to a certain network and not every network? I’ve got a couple scripts I would like to run when it connects to that specific company WiFi, one which starts up my VPN client (openconnect) and makes it ready for me to just type in my password for the VPN and some others to start an socks-tunnel and mount all my network shares.

I’ve already tried out cuttlefish (most likely not being developed any more, could only find an old client....), but found it buggy and sometimes launched a task multiple times if it launched anything at all.

Btw, I’m on Ubuntu 19.10.

Hope someone know what to do, any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: When a connection starts/stops, the scripts in `/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/` (or `/etc/networkd-dispatcher/` on servers and headless systems) are run. Each script is passed the $INTERFACE (wlan0) and the $ACTION (connect to "FooAP") each time an action occurs. You can create a script that listens for the correct combination of $INTERFACE and $ACTION, and then launches (or disconnects) your VPN.

Comment: "Our WiFi is setup in a way that we only may connect and get access to the internal business resources if you’ve got an managed Windows client." Have you tried *user-agent-switcher* for Firefox? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @user535733
I tried to create a script, and it worked just fine when i didnt have the if statement in it. Is there something i misunderstood? In kinda new to scripting, as i havent needed to actually script anything yet, but understand often whats written if someone writes it. It just locks up NetworkManager and wont allow me to access any WiFies after I've connected to the hotspot

This is the script i tried to make
#!/bin/bash
if ['$INTERFACE'=='wlp61s0'] && [ $ACTION == HUAWEI P20 ]; then
xterm -hold -e vpn &
socks
mount -a
fi
This should be an separate file in that directory?

Comment: See https://blog.dbi-services.com/catching-interface-state-changes-with-network-manager/ for an example script to get you started catching the correct events.